# Auto-click on specific area in image

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my simple HTML page and I want to target the specific area to auto click on the blue area after page load. Can anyone create an HTML, PHP or JavaScript file for me?

HTML page: http://imgily.com/Speific-Area-Click.html

Example screenshot of specific area:

[image]

Comment: This is not a "do it for me" website. We try to assist and help where we can, but your question is not clear enough for us to help. Have a look through [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. Show us some research, and some code samples, and we would be happy to help.

Comment: Is this blue area  a dive image or what.. it would be better if you can paste your code too

Comment: @deanna please consider doing something on your own.. SO is not about to help you make whole programs of applications... thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use html2canvas for capture your screen area and transform to canvas.

Then you can iterate thought the canvas and find the blue pixel (make an algo)..

```
// Do something like that
html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var context = canvas.getContext();
        var imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width,canvas.height);
        var data = imgData.data;

        // enumerate all pixels
        // each pixel's r,g,b,a datum are stored in separate sequential array elements
        // from : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714742/looping-through-pixels-in-an-image

        for(var i=0; i < data.length; i+=4) {
            var red = data[i];
            var green = data[i+1];
            var blue = data[i+2];
            var alpha = data[i+3];


        }
    }
});
```

Comment: hy i need your help please give your email id.thanks?

Comment: how can you conclude that `data[i+2] = blue`?? and using canvas for this simple thing is not suggestible...

Comment: hey thanks for your answer,can you please tell me about auto ad click script? example html page :   http://healthtips2.ml/Health-and-Wellness-Products.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use `document.ready` function of jquery..
**put a button at that blue area (i.e you can apply some css to that button which will make it with same look and feel)**

```
<input type='button' id='button' />
```

and you can trigger an click event using jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $("#button").trigger('click'); 
    });
</script>
```

**OR**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function(){
       jQuery('#button').click();
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT**

for the html link you provided you should use script like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $("#google_image_div a").trigger('click'); 
    });
</script>
```

let me know if any help needed..

Comment: hey thanks for your answer,can you please tell me about auto ad click script? example html page :   http://healthtips2.ml/Health-and-Wellness-Products.html

Comment: hey @nishant-solanki Please send your email id or email me at DeanaJasmine5555@gmail.com . Need some help. Thanks