# Flood Fill Algorithm implementation in java script

Tags: javascript, flood-fill

i new in java script trying to implement flood fill in java script by load image(sketch)  from PC to canvas but could not 
IF anyone can help me i will be very thankful 
thanks in advance

Comment: just able to add image to canvas here's  my code

var can = document.getElementById('canvas');

var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();

img.onload = function()
{
    can.width = img.width;

    can.height = img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
}
img.src = 'zlati-nathalie.jpg';

Answer (score 0):

To draw an image to the canvas, the iamge has to be loaded first.
Here is an example on how to draw to the canvas:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  //draw after loading
  canvas = document.getElementById('case_canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
}

img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgNw7.png";
//^^ this will start loading the image
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pmeb1uhm/1/

Please notice: you may have issues drawing an image located on your system due to security (cross-origin policy) limitations. You should see an error coming up on your browsers dev-console.
Instead of changing your browsers security settings I highly recommend to run your scripts on localhost and load the image using localhost.

Comment: thanks it worked for me 
now can you please help to implement flood fill 
i will be very thankful

Comment: now you have to access the pixel-array to start the algorithm. And this where cross origin policy may cause issues if you're not working on a local server.
There are a lot of sources to get started, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714742/looping-through-pixels-in-an-image.
The important thing here is: you're getting an array including rows/cols/r,g,b,a values